# How can I get the item name on top of the screen back in FTB Infinity Evolved?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I accidentally pushed a button and now I can't see the little description that displays at the top of the screen when you look at a block.

What should I do? Because I really would like to know what can be harvested with what tool.

Answer (score 2):

The description you are talking about is from the WAILA ("What Am I Looking At?") mod.

The [mod page](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1289765-waila-1-5-7-for-1-7-10-1-6-0-for-1-8-1) states that the mod comes with two keybindings, one for options and one for show/hide:

> There are 2 keybindings you want to check. [Waila] Config menu will allow you to setup which key pop up the menu (default to numpad0) while [Waila] Show/Hide will control (default numpad1) show/hide of the tooltip (will also be used for the maintened mode).

Try pressing <kbd>Num 1</kbd> on your keyboard. If you have a notebook, you might not have a physical Numpad. In this case, <kbd>Num 1</kbd> is typically something like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

If <kbd>Num 1</kbd> does not work (modpacks may change default keybindings to avoid conflicts), check the keybindings in the settings. There should be one for "Show/Hide" under WAILA.